# Nesesito hacer este documento en latex y no me sale

Tags: table, latex

Hola necesito hacer un documento en latex pero no me sale, tengo esto

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
        node[american xor port]{} % Mejor con la pancita mas redonda no se como
        
        ;
        \end{circuitikz}

        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            X & Y & S \\
            \hline
            0 & 0 & 0 \\
            \hline
            0 & 1 & 1 \\
            \hline
            1 & 0 & 1 \\
            \hline
            1 & 1 & 0 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}


        % I want the O with x inside
X Ox Y
    
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
                \multicolumn{ 3}{l}{Input} & \multicolumn{ 2}{l}{Output} \\ \hline
                X0 & X1 & X2 & A & B \\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
                0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
                1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
                1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
                1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
                \hline
            \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Este codigo es en latex y me da esto
[image: esto]

Lo que quiero es que el simbolo del xor la tabla y la formaula esten en la misma linea. Despues abajo la tabla en el centro y abajo de la tabla estas dos fotos

[image: foto1] [image: foto2]

No entiendo porque me lo separa todo en lineas y no lo pone recto y si alguien puede ayudarme a poner las tablas mejor estaria bien porque no entiendo bien lo de tabular (lo intente hacer de algunas formas pero me sale error en texmaker) Gracias a todos anticipadas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como complemento a la respuesta de abulafia te dejo un ejemplo de como usar el paquete `karnaugh-map`.

En el primer caso incluyo los términos de forma manual con `\manualterms`, en el segundo utilizando `minterms` y `maxterms` para que veas que hay varias formas [(mira la documentación)](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/karnaugh-map/karnaugh-map.pdf)

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\begin{document}
    \begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][][]
        \manualterms{0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1}
        \implicant{1}{7}
        \implicant{7}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
    \qquad
    \begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][][]
        \minterms{2,3,5,6,7}
        \maxterms{0,1,4}
        \implicant{3}{6}
        \implicant{5}{7}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
\end{document}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ok gracias fran esto es lo que buscaba no como lo hacia abulfia que quedaba mal. me as ayudado mucho

Comment: @JhonCor Muchas gracias por lo que me toca... :-/

Comment: @JhonCor creo que no son las formas. No estas haciendo las cosas bien. Abulafia te ha dado una pedazo de respuesta y no solo que te ha dado el código sino que te ha explicado los puntos más importantes. Además ha investigado sobre el paquete `karnaugh-map` para darte una respuesta completa. Plantéate como has actuado en este hilo y aprende para futuras intervenciones. Para terminar, imagino que habrás pecado de novato y por eso has marcado la respuesta correcta la mía, cuando indico que es un complemento a la respuesta de abulafia (que es la mejor respuesta), cámbialo para no liar a nadie.

Comment: @abulafia y fran no queria faltar al respeto. perdon. me an ayudado mucho deverdad pero abulfia no sabe electronico y a echo el mapa mal al final por eso mejor respuesta es fran pero gracias igual ya tengo mi pdf en texmaker. cambio la respuesta o doy puntos

Comment: No estoy aqui por los puntos :-) Pero agradezco las palabras de @fran y me siento resarcido. jhonCor ¿podrías decirme qué está mal en mi mapa de karnaugh? Aunque mi especialidad no es la electrónica, si que hice mapas de estos hace tiempo, pero lo tenía un poco olvidado. Al revisar los ejemplos de la documentación del paquete lo fui recordando y creia haberlo hecho bien ¿dónde fallé?

Comment: @JhonCor la idea es que marques su respuesta como la mejor para los que tengan tu misma duda en un futuro puedan localizar mejor la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Varias cosas:

1. Para que te quede todo en una misma línea en el resultado, en el fuente no debe haber líneas vacías por el medio de las cosas, pues una línea vacía para TeX significa un "párrafo nuevo".

   Si quieres separar en el fuente las cosas verticalmente para tenerlas mejor organizadas visualmente, en lugar de líneas en blanco puedes usar líneas "comentadas" (un simple `%`) que evita que TeX lo tome por una marca de "párrafo nuevo".
2. Para que la puerta lógica salga alineada hacia el centro de la tabla, puedes ponerle la opción `[baseline]`
3. El símbolo para XOR no es una X en un círculo, sino un + en un círculo. En LaTeX esto se obtiene con `$\oplus$`
4. Las fotos se insertan con un `\includegraphics{}`. Para que las dos salgan en la misma línea, lo antes dicho, no debe haber líneas en blanco entre ambas en el código fuente. Para que las fotos salgan de un tamaño adecuado puedes usar su opción `[width=]` al que le podrías pasar una dimensión en centímetros, pero puede ser más útil pasarle  por ejemplo `0.3\textwidth`, que quiere decir "un tercio del ancho de la línea de texto".
5. Para separar un poco verticalmente las cosas en el pdf, puedes usar `\vskip` y pasarle cuántos centímetros o milímetros de separación quieres. También es habitual en lugar de poner una cantidad prefijada usar la almacenada en la variable `\baselineskip`, que contiene la distancia entre líneas usada en ese documento.
6. Si quieres separar horizontalmente las cosas para que no queden muy pegadas unas a otras, puedes usar `\quad` o `\qquad` (el segundo es un espacio más ancho que el primero)
7. Para que todo te quede centrado horizontalmente, metelo todo en un entorno `center`.

Poniendo todo esto en práctica, el TeX quedaría así:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline]
    \draw  node[american xor port,name=X] {}; % Mejor con la pancita mas redonda no se como
    \end{circuitikz}
%    
    \qquad
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            X & Y & S \\
            \hline
            0 & 0 & 0 \\
            \hline
            0 & 1 & 1 \\
            \hline
            1 & 0 & 1 \\
            \hline
            1 & 1 & 0 \\
            \hline
    \end{tabular}
%    
    % I want the O with x inside
    \qquad X $\oplus$ Y

    \vskip\baselineskip
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \multicolumn{ 3}{l}{Input} & \multicolumn{ 2}{l}{Output} \\ \hline
        X0 & X1 & X2 & A & B \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
        0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vskip2\baselineskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{foto1}\qquad\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{foto2}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Y esta es la página resultante:

[image: Pagina resultante]

### Ampliación

La distancia horizontal entre los elementos de la primera línea se puede alterar a base de poner más `\quad` o `\qquad` entre ellos. La distancia vertical entre elementos de la página se puede controlar con el `\vskip`.

Las tablas se pueden mejorar con ayuda del paquete `booktabs`. Un consejo general para hacer tablas más bonitas es evitar en lo posible las líneas horizontales y verticales dentro de ellas. En tu caso puede ser necesaria una línea vertical para separar inputs de outputs, pero nada más. Y las únicas horizontales necesarias son las que delimitan la cabecera de la tabla y su final, y no las que hay entre sus filas.

Así por ejemplo la primera tabla podría escribirse como:

```
    \begin{tabular}{cc|c}
        \toprule
        X & Y & S \\
        \midrule
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

Y la segunda así:

```
    \begin{tabular}{ccc|cc}
    \toprule
     \multicolumn{ 3}{c}{Input} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{Output} \\
        X0 & X1 & X2 & A & B \\
     \midrule
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

Se requiere `\usepackage{booktabs}` en el preámbulo, y el resultado sería este:

[image: Tablas mejoradas]

En cuanto al diagrama de Karnaugh, tienes el paquete `karnaugh-map` que es precisamente para hacer ese tipo de diagramas. No obstante no es mi especialidad la electrónica, por lo que no acabo de entender bien todas las opciones del paquete. Creo que lo siguiente hace lo que buscas:

```
\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][$X_0 X_2$][$X_1$]
    \maxterms{0,2,4}
    \minterms{1,3,5,6,7}
    \implicant{1}{7}
    \implicant{7}{6}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
}
\quad
\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][$X_0 X_2$][$X_1$]
    \maxterms{0,1,4}
    \minterms{2,3,5,6,7}
    \implicant{3}{6}
    \implicant{5}{7}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
}
```

Estos son los diagramas resultantes:

[image: Mapas de Karnaugh]

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme. Pero los mapas de karnaug de abajo como los hago en latex? y los tres elementos de arriba no se pueden separar para que queden mejor? igual que las tablas dejarlas mejor que e visto algunos pdfs con tablas bien hechas

Comment: Cuando dijiste en la pregunta "abajo de la tabla estas dos fotos" entendí que querías incluirlas como imágenes externas, ya que te referiste a ellas como "fotos". ¿Cuánto quieres separar los tres elementos de arriba? ¿Qué entiendes por "dejar las tablase mejor"?  ¡Son muchas preguntas en una! Para no andar dando palos de ciego igual era mejor que pusieras en la pregunta una imagen de cómo querrías que te quedara (aunque sea un boceto a mano)

Comment: no perdon queria ponerlas en latex mejor.  perdon. separarlos mas, no se como decirte pero tampoco mucho mas.

Comment: Cada `\quad` o `\quad` que pongas las separa un poco más dentro de la misma línea. Ve probando hasta que quede a tu gusto. Si te referías a separar esa primera línea de la tabla que hay debajo prueba a cambiar la cantidad tras `\vskip`

Comment: ok ya lo consegui gracias. sabes hacer lo del karnaug ?

Comment: sin la flecha esa de la izquierda que no la quiero ni los numeros que hay dentro de los cuadrados

Comment: @JhonCor mira el paquete `karnaugh-map`

Comment: ok gracias abulfia me as ayudado mucho. a ver si alguien ayuda con eso de karnaug porque yo tampoco entiendo los documentos